# border radius misbehaving

Tags: firefox, border, css

In FF this border radius doesn't seem to want to work.
[Editable](http://jsfiddle.net/5gkVS/) link here.

The right radius of the big box should be 0px and the left of the small box should be 0 to join them.

HTML:

```
<fieldset class="error">
    <input id="product__79_specField_8" name="specField_8" class="text " autocomplete="" type="text" value=""/>
    <input type="image" src="upload/orng_bg_arrow"upload/id="product__specfield_8_arrow" value=""></input>
    <div class="errorText hidden"></div>
</fieldset>
```

CSS

```
#product__79_specField_8,
#product___specField_8 {
    background-color:#ffa105;
    width:194px;
    height:33px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-right-radius:0px;
    font-weight:bold;
    font-size:24px;
    padding-left:55px;
    float:left;
}

#product__specfield_8_arrow {
    background-color:#ffa105;
    width:50px;
    height:33px;
    border: 1px solid #dddddd;
    border-left:none;
    border-radius:5px;
    -moz-border-radius:5px;
    -webkit-border-radius:5px;
    border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -moz-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:0px;
    -webkit-border-top-left-radius:0px;
    margin:0;
    padding:2px;
}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Unfortunately, the forms of the CSS attributes vary between webkit and mozilla.

For Firefox, you want:

```
-moz-border-radius-bottomright:
-moz-border-radius-bottomleft:
-moz-border-radius-topright:
-moz-border-radius-topleft:
```

For Safari & Chrome you want:

```
-webkit-border-top-left-radius:    
-webkit-border-top-right-radius:
-webkit-border-bottom-left-radius:
-webkit-border-bottom-right-radius:
```

You seem to have:

```
-moz-border-bottom-right-radius:0px;
-moz-border-top-right-radius:0px;
```

which isn't valid.

Answer (score 2):

`-moz-border-radius-topright: 0px`

http://www.css3.info/preview/rounded-border/

Answer (score 2):

Your declarations are a bit off, the mozilla styles should be like this:

```
#product___specField_8 {
  -moz-border-radius-bottomright:0px;
  -moz-border-radius-topright:0px;
}

#product__specfield_8_arrow {
  -moz-border-radius-topleft:0px;
  -moz-border-radius-bottomleft:0px
}
```

[For a good equality comparison across all 3, look here](http://www.the-art-of-web.com/css/border-radius/)

Answer (score 0):

**Solution:**

```
-moz-border-radius:5px 10px 150 20px;
-webkit-border-radius:5px 10px 150 20px;
border-radius:5px 10px 150 20px;
```

Here, 

5px is for top left corner,

10px is for top right corner,

15px is for bottom right corner,

20px is for bottom left corner.